# Assign updated variable data to a TextBlock everytime a button is clicked

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, desktop-application

I'm trying to create a small program whereas if you click the increase button, the number will add 1, and vice versa for the decrease button.

I managed to bind the _number value to the TextBlock (initially set as 0), but when I click the buttons, none seem to add or subtract the value. Or if the value changed but didn't update on the window.

.xaml

```
// MainWindow.xaml
<Window x:Class="Home_Test.MainWindow"
    ...
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid Name="MainGrid">
    <Button ...
            Content="Add" 
            Click="increase"/>
    <Button ...
            Content="Subtract"
            Click="decrease"/>
    <TextBlock 
             Name="txtbox"
             HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
             Height="23" 
             TextWrapping="Wrap" 
             Text="{Binding Path=Number}" 
             Width="120"
             Margin="0,100,0,0" />
</Grid>
```

.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
...

namespace Home_Test
{
    public partial class MainWindow : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }

    private int _number = 0;
    public int Number
    {
        get { return _number; }
        set
        {
            if (_number != value)
            {
                _number = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public void increase(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _number += 1;
    }
    public void decrease(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _number -= 1;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

}

Overall, I expected my program to add 1 or subtract 1 when I click the button.
Am I doing anything wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea, but you have a couple of missing pieces:

1) The XAML UI is monitoring the `Number` property for changes so it can update, but your `increase()` and `decrease()` methods are only updating the backing variable. You have to set the `Number` property directly.

2) Your setter method on `Number` needs to tell the XAML UI to update when it is changed. This is done by invoking the OnPropertyChangedEvent in the property setter - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-to-implement-the-inotifypropertychanged-interface  (It talks about windows forms but the mechanism is the same)

Answer (score 1):

Your XAML looks good.  Just to clarify though, you did not bind `_number` to the TextBlock.  `_number` is a private variable, and is not accessible to the UI.  You data-bound the public property `Number` to TextBlock, as you should have.

As MarcE was describing in his post, the trouble comes about in your ViewModel.  The Setter of your `Number` property needs a call to your PropertyChanged method, which needs to be added; and your increase and decrease methods need to modify the `Number` property directly rather than its backing variable.
When you just modify the backing variable, the setter of your property never gets called, and therefor the UI never gets updated.

Shown below are the code modifications needed:

```
private int _number = 0;
public int Number
{
    get { return _number; }
    set
    {
        if (_number != value)
        {
            _number = value;
            //After the setter updates the backing variable, this Updates the UI.
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Number");
        }
    }
}

public void increase(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Number += 1;
}
public void decrease(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Number -= 1;
}
```

Add this code for the `NotifyPropetyChanged` functionality to work.

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
  if (PropertyChanged != null)
  {
    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}
```

Your were most of the way there.

Answer (score -1):

The set method of the number property is not firing the OnPropertyChanged event. Check here for details https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification